# Some overlays are black

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, mesh, 3d-view

Guys I convert my levels from Valve Hammer Editor to Blender, but sadly they look black in render. How do fix this?

https://ibb.co/9tL65nV
https://ibb.co/CKY2kXT
https://ibb.co/R9DkRg9

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Hello, can you kindly share your .blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/. Also, it looks like you don't have any proper lighting setup in your scene. Material preview mode has an HDRI by default, but the render doesn't. Add some lights and an HDRI to your scene if you want.

Comment: Sorry its here, https://blend-exchange.com/b/DlYvMznw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material preview mode has an HDRI by default. If you want a brighter scene in your render, then you have to add some lights and also add an HDRI if you want. You haven't provided your .blend file, but it looks like your scene is lit up by the default grey environment colour and a dim lamp. See here how to add an HDRI/light or increase the power of your HDRI/light:[image][image][image]

**EDIT:** Your objects are intersecting, which causes the problem:[image] You'll have to remove the intersection or delete the intersecting parts in some way. You could mix the materials together without using another plane, but if you don't want that, just very slightly move the planes forward by pressing `Shift` after the grab operation to do incremental movements, stop the intersecting and go to object properties>visibility>uncheck shadow if you can see it casting a shadow on your wall after moving.

Comment: There is a light in my level but changing it didn't solve my problems, there are still black and white bars in render. Is it because I convert from VHE.

Comment: @Göktuğ check my edits.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, then I am slightly moving my intersected objects towards the wall. My last question, there are some overlays with white background in the level. Moving them didn't disappear their whiteness. Blender doesn't recognize them as transparent?

Comment: @Göktuğ Blender, before seeing the transparency, also notices that the meshes are ntersecting. That makes it confused which one to display, and even though the other one is transparent, it renders it as black. Though I don't understand by what you mean by "moving them didn't disappear their whiteness"

Comment: As you said I am fixing my overlays with slightly moving them to separate.  I mean this. But on the last picture there is a crack overlay on tiles, couldn't fix this.

Comment: @Göktuğ instead of moving it back, move it slightly forward.